# wiping iPod and putting back all the music

Tags: ipod

I am trying to sync podcasts with my iPod Classic, but the podcasts are not transferring over.

How do I figure out what is going wrong here?

Comment: Why does the title of your question have absolutely nothing to do with what your real question was?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the Podcasts sync options in iTunes, found under your iPod Classic pane?

[image: Podcast Options found in iTunes]

Comment: Note: The iPod needs to be connected to see the sync options.